# How to call AsyncTask from a service or better way for background updating

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I am working on app, right now it pulls data from twitter and updates the IU on a button press. I want to automate that so it will update every hour in the background and eventually get it to send a notification from the background as well.

I can call an AsyncTask with an update button which accesses twitter and updates text and icons in a UI thread. I also have a service which I can turn on and off with a checkbox. Can I call my AsyncTask from the service and get it to auto update or is there something else I should be doing instead?

Here is my stripped down code for the Main:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    lastUpdate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lastUpdate);

    //checkbox starts and stops service "TheService"
    CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.check_box);

    checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
                startService(new Intent(MainActivity.this, TheService.class));
            }else{
                stopService(new Intent(MainActivity.this, TheService.class));
            }
        }
    });

}

//This function is called when button is clicked.
public void startTask(View view) {
    myAsyncTask mTask = new myAsyncTask();
    mTask.execute("abc", "10", "Hello world");
}

public class myAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... arg) {
        try {
         //accesses twitter here
        } catch (TwitterException te) {
            System.exit(-1);
        }

        //New thread is created because this function can't update UI Thread.
        runOnUiThread(new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                TextView lastUpdate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lastUpdate);
                     //change text and icons on screen here
                lastUpdate.setText("Last updated: " + currentTime);
            }
        });
        return null;
    }
}
}
```

Service:

```
public class TheService extends Service {
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Service created!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Service stopped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
}
```

Comment: You can not change UI in dobackground() you have to change UI in Post or progress method in async task

Comment: @MilindVyas I create a new thread to run It on. The code I have works I am looking for for help implementing some new features in the background.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

its better to use thread inside service instead for your server request or repeated or fix interval request and use broadcast receiver or LocalBroadcastManager and send that broadcast from service or thread to update ui in your activity do not forget to register and unregister reciver when your app is on resume(), on pause() or on stop() state otherwise it leak.keep in mind that Service is not background Thread is simple balnk ui you have to create thread inside service for server request. also you can find better SO thread and tutorial by searching regarding your question. hope you will understand.

Comment: Thanks, I understand what you mean but I am not sure how I would implement that. I have only been working with android for a couple weeks and this is my first attempt and anything in the background. Would you mind going into more detail or know of an example I can model after?

Comment: if u seems right that my answer is fit to your qustion than you can accept my answer.

Comment: i am giving some of tutorial reference  of online https://www.websmithing.com/2011/02/01/how-to-update-the-ui-in-an-android-activity-using-data-from-a-background-service/